# Mysql query from 3 tables and where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables in my Database

```
# Items
id - name 
----------
1  -  Item A 
2  -  Item B 
3  -  Item C
```

.

```
# Traits 
id - name 
----------
1  - Color
2  - Grade
3  - Size
```

.

```
# Values  
id - item_id - trait_id - value  
----------
1  - 1  - 1  - red 
1  - 2  - 1  - green 
1  - 3  - 1  - red 
1  - 1  - 2  - 90% 
1  - 2  - 2  - 45% 
1  - 3  - 2  - 80%
1  - 1  - 3  - 4 inches
1  - 2  - 3  - 5 inches
1  - 3  - 3  - 9 inches
```

In Laravel, I could get all items with their traits and values using "belongsTo" [$this->belongsTo('App\Traits','trait_id');] in Value model to get the results like so :

```
--- Item A 
Color: red
Grade: 90%
Size: 4 inches

--- Item B 
Color: green
Grade: 45%
Size: 5 inches

.. etc
```

from code like this :

```
$items = Items::get();
foreach ($items as $item) {
  echo '<h2>'.$item->name.'</h2>';
  foreach ($item->values as $value) {
      echo '<b>'.$value->trait->name . '</b>: ';
      echo $value->value . '<br>';
  }
}
```

**However, what I couldn't do is that I need to filter these results, for examples, I only need Items that its color is "red" and its grade bigger than 70% ?**

If you don't use Larave, feel free to write it in pure mysql queries, I may find a way to do it in Laravel when I get the idea.. Thank you

Comment: `id` serves no purpose in the values table (which is, btw, a poor choice of name). A good tip, if using an EAV model, is to construct separate tables for each data type.

Comment: @Strawberry Actually it's first time I know about EAV model, all structures above came from my head without knowing anything about EAV, I'll read more about it and see what's best practice for such an approach, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering items/entities by (multiple) attribute-value pairs is one of the disadvantages of the [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). There some ways to achieve that. One is to join the `Items` table with `Traits` and `Values` once per condition:

```sql
select i.*
from Items i
join `Values` v1 on v1.item_id = i.id
join `Values` v2 on v2.item_id = i.id
join Traits t1 on t1.id = v1.trait_id
join Traits t2 on t2.id = v2.trait_id
where t1.name = 'Color' and v1.value = 'red'
  and t2.name = 'Grade' and v2.value > 70
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/263ba1/24)

You can also use pivoting to get a result with the columns (item_id, Color, Grade):

```sql
select v.item_id
  , max(case when t.name = 'Color' then v.value end) as Color
  , max(case when t.name = 'Grade' then v.value end) as Grade
from `Values` v
join Traits t on t.id = v.trait_id
group by v.item_id
having Color = 'red' and Grade > 70
```

This result can be joined with the `Items` table to get the filtered Items. A modification can also be used in a WHERE-IN condition:

```sql
select * from Items
where id in (
  select v.item_id
  from `Values` v
  join Traits t on t.id = v.trait_id
  group by v.item_id
  having max(case when t.name = 'Color' then v.value end) = 'red'
     and max(case when t.name = 'Grade' then v.value end) > 70
);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/263ba1/40)

Another approach:

```sql
select * from Items
where id in (
  select v.item_id
  from `Values` v
  join Traits t on t.id = v.trait_id
  where t.name = 'Color' and v.value = 'red'
     or t.name = 'Grade' and v.value > 70
  group by v.item_id
  having count(v.item_id) = 2
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul! First time I know about the EAV model, I'll read more about it.